# Kendo UI, datagrid inserted row produces request multiple times

Tags: javascript, datagrid, kendo-ui, telerik, transport

i have problem with Kendo data grid component.

I'm trying to add new row into grid and create remote request to API via create event.

Problem is that if i try to add new row after first request Kendo make 2 requests instead of the one.

[image: Screen]

I tried to find some solution for this using transport create and options.success method but without luck.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.create

Could somebody tell to me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Here is the code of the server response for create:

```
+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
           "status": "OK",
           "result":[
                {
                    "id":22,
                    "username":"blahblah",
                    "name":"Thomas",
                    "surname":"Man",
                    "email":"to.mas.marny@gmail.com",
                    "created":"1399986964",
                    "role":"USER"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Here is the code of the method:

```
   $scope.initGrid = function () {

        // get access token from localstorage
        var token = localStorage
            .getItem($rootScope.lsTokenNameSpace);
        // set pagination data
        var paginationData = {
            "token": token,
            "data": {
                "page": 1,
                "items_per_page": 20
            }
        };
        var dataPacket;

        dataPacket = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "user/list",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON
                            .stringify(paginationData),
                        success: function (
                            response) {
                            console
                                .log("List of users succesfully obtained");
                            console
                                .log(response.result);
                            // pass response to
                            // model
                            options
                                .success(response);
                            // $notification.enableHtml5Mode();
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console
                                .log("user list request error");
                            console.log(error);
                            $notification
                                .error(
                                    "User list cannot be loaded",
                                    "Please try again in a minute.");
                        }
                    });
                },
                update: function (options) {
                    console.log("Update");
                    options
                        .success("{\"test\":\"test\"}");
                },
                destroy: function (options) {
                    console.log("destroy");
                    options
                        .success("{\"test\":\"test\"}");
                },
                create: function (options) {
                    console.log("Create");
                    console.log(options.data);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "user/create",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON
                            .stringify(options.data),
                        success: function (
                            response) {
                            console
                                .log("New user created");
                            console
                                .log(response.status);
                            // pass response to
                            // model
                            options
                                .success(response.result);
                            // $notification.enableHtml5Mode();
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log("user list request error");
                            console.log(error);
                            $notification
                                .error(
                                    "User cannot be created",
                                    "Please try again in a minute.");
                        }
                    });
                },
                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                }
            },


            //batch : true,
            //autoSync: true,
            schema: {
                data: "result",
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        id: {
                            editable: false,
                            nullable: true
                        },
                        name: {
                            editable: true,
                            nullable: false
                        },
                        username: {
                            editable: true,
                            nullable: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataPacket,
            filterable: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            pageable: true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: ["id", "name", "username", {
                command: ["edit", "destroy"],
                title: " ",
                width: "200px"
            }],
            editable: "inline"
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you declare id inside model then you don't have to declare id inside model fields.
2. Also when you point

   data: "result"

for the model you have to pass

```
options.success(response)
```

inside ajax's success function, not just

```
options.success(response.result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if null is passed to the  Datasource of the kendo Grid in the html helper, the Grid will be built in “remote  data mode” rather than “local data mode” 
and since the read Url is not set the current browser Url will be used for the read operation.
 **make sure to initialize the list in the Model before using it as a Datasource.**